# Android: Using a getStyle() method for underlinespan to remove the span

Tags: java, android, html, underline, spannablestring

I'm looking for a way to determine if the character or string is underlined using a method similar to the `getStyle()` method for StyleSpan objects, but for an UnderlineSpan object instead.

Here's an example using the StyleSpan class, I need a way to test if the text is underlined in a similar method:

```
StyleSpan[] rt = str.getSpans(selectionStart, selectionEnd, StyleSpan.class);
boolean exists = false;
for (int i = 0; i < rt.length; i++) {
    if (rt[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.ITALIC){
        str.removeSpan(rt[i]);
        exists = true;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this for UnderlineSpan objects?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just change the StyleSpan.class parameter in the getSpans() call to UnderlineSpan.class.

Comment: Doesn't work, I get a swiggly line underneath telling me to turn it to a styleSpan

Comment: Did you change the left-hand-side of the assignment also? They need to match, i.e. you need to have UnderlineSpan[] rt = ...

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I tried UnderlineSpan on both the left and right side, but there doesnt seem to be a getStyle() method that pops up. UnderlineSpan[] rt = s.getSpans(styleStart, position, UnderlineSpan.class);

Comment: The line with getStyle() is just checking that the style is ITALIC, so it can just remove the italic style spans. You don't need to do that, because presumably you want to remove all underline spans. So you can replace that whole if() statement with just str.removeSpan(rt[i]);

Comment: I'm well aware you can remove the if statement and it still works, however I wanted to know if theres a way to test to see if its underlined for a different purpose, but I guess since its just an underlineSpan its not going to have a way to check the typeFace since its only one style. I guess I'll just close this question.